# How does the CSS3 :nth-child() Selector work?

Tags: css

Can anyone explain me how CSS3 :nth-child() selector works?

In the example below, the first `<p>` element is selected despite `:nth-child(n)` having a value of 2.

```css
p:nth-child(2) {
    background: #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<h1>This is a heading</h1>
<p>The first paragraph.</p>
<p>The second paragraph.</p>
<p>The third paragraph.</p>
<p>The fourth paragraph.</p>

<p><b>Note:</b> Internet Explorer 8 and earlier versions do not support the :nth-child() selector.</p>
```

Comment: can you plz elaborate as I am confused. I am adding pesudo class to P element so if index is 0 it should select third element that is '<p>The third paragraph.</p>' else if index is 1 it should select third element that is '<p>The second paragraph.</p>' ..... but here its selecting first element '<p>The first paragraph.</p>'

Comment: `p:nth-of-type(2) { background: #red; }` will select your second paragraph (if that's what you wanted to do in the first place).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good example to understand the `nth-child`property can be a list.

```css
li:nth-child(2) {
  background: red;
 }
```

```html
<h1>This is a heading</h1>
<ul>
  <li>The first element.</li>
  <li>The second element.</li>
  <li>The third element.</li>
  <li>The fourth element.</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 4):

That selector will select **all of the elements that are n-th children of their parents**. In your case, `p` is the second child of it's parent `<body>`, so it gets selected.

Run this snippet to verify the behavior:

```css
p:nth-child(2) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<!-- body is a first parent -->
<body>
  <span>First child of body</span>
  <p>Second child of body</p>

  <!-- div is a second parent, whose children are also considered -->
  <div>
    <p>First child of div</p>
    <p>Second child of div</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: you mean to say it will select parent as body and index(1) will start from <h1> tag .... am I write?

Comment: Yep, `<body>` will be a parent, `h1` - first child, `p` - the second one

Answer (score 0):

The `:nth-child(n)` selector matches every element that is the nth child, **regardless of type**, of its parent (i.e., in your case the `<body>`). The `:nth-child(2)` in your example is `<p>The first paragraph.</p>`.

Here's an example that hopefully will illuminate that the type is not what matters but the position of the child element in relation to its parent:

```css
h1:nth-child(2) {
  background: #f00;
}

h2:nth-child(2) {
  background: #ff0;
}

h3:nth-child(2) {
  background: #f0f;
}

h4:nth-child(2) {
  background: #0ff;
}

h5:nth-child(2) {
  background: #00f;
}
```

```html
<h1>This is a h1 heading.</h1>
<h2>The is a h2 heading.</h2>
<h3>The is a h3 heading.</h3>
<h4>The is a h4 heading.</h4>
<h5>The is a h5 heading.</h5>

<h1>This is a h1 heading.</h1>
<h2>The is a h2 heading.</h2>
<h3>The is a h3 heading.</h3>
<h4>The is a h4 heading.</h4>
<h5>The is a h5 heading.</h5>
```